# Twilio iOS SDK incoming call not received

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have an app where users on the app can make and receive calls. I'm having an issue where, when an outside user (+1234567890) is trying to call the Twilio number and connect with user `john`, client app is not receiving the incoming call.

User (+1234567890) calls Twilio number, when connected it dials the user `john` which is on the client app.

Access token is created with `incomingAllow` permission. `identity` also matches with the TwiML response of the incoming call function.

```
<Response >
   <Dial callerId="+1234567890">
      <Client><Identity>john</Identity></Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Call logs on the dashboard shows status as not answered.

[image: call logs]

I referred voice-quickstart-ios sample app. (https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios) My code is basically the same.

`TwilioVoiceSDK.register(accessToken: self.accessToken, deviceToken: cachedDeviceToken)`

Above function returns success as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Apple push certificate id on Twilio Credentials was not enabled for Sandbox environment.

[image]